# How to filter android logcat by exact word and space between words?

Tags: regex, android-studio, logcat

for example if I have

```
private String TAG ="Preview"; 
......
Log.d(TAG,"Preview Start");
```

and Set logcat filter to Preview
then all logs contain Preview will come up
"DrawPreview" "ActivityPreview" etc.What I want is just "Preview"

another case is when I have space in the TAG

```
    private String TAG ="Main Activity"; 
    ......
    Log.d(TAG,"Main Activity Start");
```

Logcat filter only recongnise the first word, other stuff after space is ignored.

Comment: can i know what you need exactly using logcat

Comment: To see app debug logs what else you would expect from logcat.

Comment: check with the below code which might help you to understand in more precise manner

Answer (score 2):

To match exact word you should use pattern

```
^EXACT_WORLD_TO_MATCH$
```

in the logcat filter

I still dont know how to include space between them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP is asking specifically about the case where there *is* a space between words

Comment: OP is asking for both, and this should work for either.

Comment: Actually you can do it using a whitespace character like `\s`. But you will also need to add a `~` in the new logcat filters: `tag~:^EXACT_WORLD_TO_MATCH$`

Answer (score 1):

Enter this as the logcat filter in the "Log Tag" field, make sure Regex is checked

```
^Main\WActivity$
```

That will match "Main Activity" and only that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Add the Unique Tags it may help you find the exact search

For Example, Refer to this one,

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(10)+1;
        Log.d("'Preview'", "Dice: "+random);
        Log.d("DrawPreview", "Dice: "+random);
        Log.d("ActivityPreview", "Dice: "+random);
```

then search debug 'preview'

you will find the extact what you need.